# Null object reference при перевороте экрана с открытым SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-search-view

Собственно, суть описана в заголовке: если при открытом `SearchView` в `toolbar'е` сменить положение экрана, то приложение крашится с ошибкой:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.MenuItem.collapseActionView()' on a null object reference
```

Сам метод `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenu);` написан в

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenu);

            ...
        }

    });
```

При этом приложение крашится не всегда, а только если выбрана не дефолтная страница `ViewPager'а`. Я так понимаю, что это происходит из-за того, что при перевороте экрана срабатывает заново метод `onCreate`, но `onCreateOptionsMenu` вызывается позже. Если способы решения проблемы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, это происходит из-за того, что вы пытаетесь манипулировать меню до его создания.

Вот вам вариант обхода.

В `onPrepareOptionsMenu` проверяйте флаг (boolean переменную `shouldCollapseActionView` класса активити, коей назначайте нужное значение в нужных местах. В вашем случае - вместо  `MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchMenu);` в слушателе смены страницы `ViewPager`.)

В зависимости от значения флага в `onPrepareOptionsMenu` раскрывайте/закрывайте searchView

Сразу после изменения значения этой переменной вызовите `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` - это заставит перерисоваться меню, вызвав метод `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

Так у вас всегда в нужном состоянии будет меню и вы сможете его безопасно менять